# Qt moving gui widget to gui thread

Tags: qt

So Qt has to have all GUI applications running in the Main GUI thread. I have a non-gui cpp that initiates a QDialog, and when I try to interact with the Widget I get `QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread`. That is what led me to discover that I needed to move the widget to the main thread. My question is how do I move `no_id_wheel_screen` to the main thread.

cpp of my non-gui thread

```
#include "gui_image_node.h"

gui_image_node::gui_image_node()
{

}

bool gui_image_node::init(int argc, char** argv)
{
    m_pThread = new QThread();

    m_no_id_wheel_screen = new no_id_wheel_screen;

    this->moveToThread(m_pThread);

    connect(m_pThread, &QThread::started, this, &gui_image_node::run);

    connect(m_no_id_wheel_screen, &no_id_wheel_screen::ReadyHollander, this, &gui_image_node::HolPub);

    hollander_pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/hollander_chat", 1);

    hol_trigger = nh.subscribe("awaiting_hollander", 1, &gui_image_node::Hollander_Screen_trigger_callback, this);

    m_pThread->start();
    return true;
}
//Where I start the widget
void gui_image_node::Hollander_Screen_trigger_callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    std::string steve = msg->data; 
    no_id_wheel_screen midscreen;
    midscreen.exec();
}
```

Comment: Why do you create the dialog in the other thread? I'd send a signal to the main UI thread with `steve` as argument and open the dialog there.

Comment: The big issue is that the non-gui thread is how I am running ROS commands. I will try initiating the widget through the mainwindow.

Answer (score 0):

@Frank Osterfeld Had the right idea. I just made another connection to MainWindow, then MainWindow executed my widget.